# Changing object in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var tab = new auiTab({
  element: document.getElementById("footer"),
  index: 1,
  repeatClick: false
}, function(ret) {
  if (ret.index == 1) {
    bottomnav1();
  }
  if (ret.index == 2) {
    var login_name = $api.getStorage('mobile');

    if (typeof(login_name) != "undefined") {
      Profile();
    } else {
      login();
      auiTab.index = 1;
    }
  }
});
```

I want to change the index value in array. As you can see, I tried updating it by using `auiTab.index = 1` and `tab = 1` (one of them should've worked according to Google). Both did not work - I am fairly new with programming. Is there something I am not aware of?

Comment: This is an object, not an array. And it should be `tab.index = 1`

Comment: This code is totally confusing. There's no array anywhere. What does the function `auiTab()` do? What is `auiTab.index`? How is the function invoked, and with what argument?

Comment: Or maybe it should be `ret.index = 1;`

Comment: in addition you should remove those `,` after `tab` object creation, because you will get syntax error